# datagridview column index

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexing

I have a form with a `DataGridView` widget and I need to get the index of the column with the selected name.

For example, let's say that I have a table with 2 columns: Name, Surname. I need a way to get index of the column name. The problem is that it changes all the time depending on the `DataSource` but that column always has the same name "Name".

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 32):

To retrieve a `DataGridView` column by name you simply reference it through the columns collection indexer:

```
datagridview1.Columns["columnName"]
```

Then you can get the column index from that column:

```
datagridview1.Columns["columnName"].Index;
```

Do note that if you use an invalid column name then this reference will return null, so you may want to check that the column reference is not null before using it, or use the columns collection `.Contains()` method first.

Comment: Just to be safe (for other users) you should check if the column exists first: datagridview1.Columns.Contains("ColumnName")

Comment: @ginalster Thanks - good point, I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, `e.ColumnIndex` will also work for this. you can check the MSDN Documentation **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index by using [the Index property of the DataGridViewColumn widget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.index%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), as such:

```
ColumnName.Index
```

This avoids the need for checking whether the column name is valid at runtime as it will generate a compilation error if the column does not exist. This also makes refactoring easier.

I recommend you give the columns a sensible name (for example `DCOL_SomeName`) so that you can easily distinguish them. Including the name of the `DataGridView` widget would help if you have multiple `DataGridView` widgets on the same form.

Answer (score 1):

create a static class below the code

```
public static class MyTools
{
    public static int IndexByName(this DataGridView dgv, string name)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if(col.HeaderText.ToUpper().Trim() == name.ToUpper().Trim())
            {
                return col.Index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

and then call it with your dataGridView

```
int index = datagridview1.IndexByName("columnName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found it safer to use the column object's Name property, instead of using the column name as a string, because this allows for more consistent code refactoring in the future.

```
datagridview1.Columns[column1.Name].Index;
```

Also, it is important to first make sure the column is not null and, as others have said, that it is contained within the datagridview.